# Multiplying complex matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to multiply two complex matrices (`b+c*i`), but I'm getting no results.

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> impedancaZ at 14
l=mtimes(R1,h)
```

I don't understand this error, as matrix dimension are the same (2 coluoms and 9 rows)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inner matrix dimensions must agree` means that the *inner* dimensions of the matrices must match.  If the first matrix has dimensions 2x`9`, then the second would need to be `9`x(something).  that's just basic liner algebra/matrix multiplication.  In that case, you'll need to figure out what the second array should be.  Maybe it's the **transpose** of what you expect it to be; instead of `x*y`, you might want `x*y'` (see the "prime" marker after the `y`?

Alternatively, maybe you want a "scalar multiply" rather than a "matrix multiply" for this.  That is, you don't want to multiply the matrices x and y in the "linear algebra" sense, but you just want to multiply the elements of the arrays, *element by element*.  In that case, you'd do `x.*y` (see the dot before the `*`?).

Unfortunately, I can't tell which is really correct for your situation without more context.  You'll either have to supply some more information or figure it out yourself from the hints I've given.